# MySQL SELECT MIN price with priority of field

Tags: mysql, sql

uI have a database with 3 price fields.
Now I want to query the smallest price in the following order

If MIN price 1 is greater 0 then price 1

ELSE If MIN price 2 is greater 0 then price 2

ELSE If MIN price 3 is greater 0 then price 3

But I always get the lowest price, no matter in which field this is

```
SELECT f.user, 
(SELECT
    (
        CASE 
        WHEN MIN(s.price2) > '0' THEN CONCAT(MIN(s.price2), '*Week*') 
        WHEN MIN(s.price1) > '0' THEN CONCAT(MIN(s.price1), '*Week*')
        WHEN MIN(s.price3) > '0' THEN CONCAT(MIN(s.price3), '*Week*')
        ELSE 0
        END
    ) 
 FROM prices s WHERE f.user = s.user
) as price FROM table f WHERE f.user = 84

+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| id   |   user | price1 | price2 | price3 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|    1 |     84 |    785 |      0 |      0 |
|    2 |     84 |    550 |    200 |    100 |
|    3 |     84 |      0 |     90 |     45 |
|    4 |     84 |      0 |      0 |     80 |
|    5 |     84 |      0 |    300 |     80 |
|    6 |     84 |    100 |     95 |      0 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

What i want: Priority has MIN price2, then MIN price1, then MIN price4.

```
+------+-------+-------+
| id   |  user | price |
+------+-------+-------+
|    1 |    84 |    90 |
+------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: You aren't comparing the price fields at all so the case evaluation will quit if price1 is > 0 which I'm guessing it always is.

Comment: Please normalize your database

Comment: `MIN(price1)` is zero (namely the one for ID 4). So it's not price1 you want to show. `MIN(price2)` is zero (in the records of ID 3 and 4). So it's not price2 you want to show either.  `MIN(price3)` is zero (in the record of ID 1). So you don't want to show price3. Which leaves us with price = 0. So the query should show zero for all IDs. The desired result you show however contains other prices. So what do you really want? Please correct your request.

Comment: Sorry, I did not express myself well. My head is buzzing.
I have revised my question. Hopefully it is understandable now.

Comment: price4 = price3 I suppose, and the strange ID in the result is probably a mistake. Do you actually need the ID (which would be 3 I surmise) in the results?

Comment: It looks like your query should produce the result shown. So how is your query's result different from what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure I understand your question correctly. You take the minumum prices:

- `MIN(price1)` = 100
- `MIN(price2)` = 90
- `MIN(price3)` = 45

`SUM(price2)` has highest priority. As it is greater than zero we return this. (Otherwise we'd check `SUM(price1)` and if that were zero or less too, we'd check `SUM(price3)`.)

```
select
  case 
    when sum(price2) > 0 then sum(price2)
    when sum(price1) > 0 then sum(price1) end
    when sum(price3) > 0 then sum(price3) end
    else 0
  end as price
from prices
where user = 84;
```